# How to update multiple rows with one single query

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I use Postgresql + PHP.

Say I have this table:

```
Books ( id, title, year )
```

and this array of titles in PHP:

```
$titles = array ("bible","kafka","Book of Eli");
```

now I want update all rows where the title is in the $titles array above.

So I need a query like this:

```
UPDATE books SET year = '2001-11-11' WHERE title is in $titles;
```

Is is possible with one single query ? Or do I need to use FOR loop ?

Comment: Are you updating the date to the same value in all cases where the title is in the array or will different titles have different dates?

Comment: yes, this is only a example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, you were actually quite close.

For the SQL, the syntax looks like this:

```
UPDATE books SET year = '2001-11-11' WHERE title IN ('bible','kafka','Book of Eli');
```

To generate that using PHP, you'll want to do something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE books SET year = '2001-11-11' WHERE title IN ('" . implode("','", $titles) . "');'";
```

The PHP `implode()` function joins array elements together using a string, so I put `','` between all of them, with the initial and final `'` being put in the string manually.

Note that this will currently fail if any of the titles contain an apostrophe. If that's a possibility you will need to escape those.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to the post.

Comment: Good answer, but the php manual says: "The query string should not end with a semicolon."

Comment: DON'T FORGET to call pg_escape_string() on those titles before imploding them!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, which will let you turn the array into a comma-separated string:

```
$titles = array ("bible","kafka","Book of Eli");
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array)
$sql = "UPDATE books SET year = '2001-11-11' WHERE title is in (" . $comma_separated .")"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$sql = "UPDATE books SET year = '2001-11-11' WHERE title in ('".implode("','",$titles)."')";
```

Comment: Forgot the first/last quotes, your string would look like: `WHERE title IN (bible','kafka','Book of Eli)`

Comment: I think you misssed the opening and closing ' you've got the ones between the imploded values.